# sort on apache poi Pivot table column

Tags: java, apache-poi, pivot-table

I am unable to sort an apache poi pivot table column. The table contains two columns. First is the key and second is the count. I want to sort on the second column. Tried the below code but it's not working.

```
pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition()
                    .getPivotFields()
                    .getPivotFieldArray(sortColumnIndex)
                    .setSortType(STFieldSortType.ASCENDING);
```

Below is the complete code:

```
public static XSSFPivotTable createPivotTable(XSSFWorkbook my_xlsx_workbook, int sheetIndex,
            int[] filterColumnIndex, int rowLabelColumnIndex, List<PivotTableColumnLabelHeaders> columnLabelHeaders,
            String pivotSheetName, Integer sortColumnIndex) throws IOException {
        /* Read Data to be Pivoted - we have only one worksheet */
        XSSFSheet sheet = my_xlsx_workbook.getSheetAt(sheetIndex);// 2
        /* Add a new sheet to create Pivot Table */
        XSSFSheet pivot_sheet = my_xlsx_workbook.createSheet(pivotSheetName);
        /* Get the reference for Pivot Data */
        AreaReference dataArea = new AreaReference(new CellReference(0, 0), // A1
                new CellReference(sheet.getLastRowNum() - 1, sheet.getRow(sheet.getLastRowNum()).getLastCellNum() - 1)// H101
                , SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007);
        /* Find out where the Pivot Table needs to be placed */
        CellReference cellRef = new CellReference("A1");
        /* Create Pivot Table on a separate worksheet */
        XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = pivot_sheet.createPivotTable(dataArea, cellRef, sheet);
        // addRowLabel(pivotTable, sheet, dataArea, 25);
        /* Add filters */
        if (filterColumnIndex.length > 0) {
            for (int i : filterColumnIndex)
                pivotTable.addReportFilter(i);
        }
        pivotTable.addRowLabel(rowLabelColumnIndex);
        for (PivotTableColumnLabelHeaders var : columnLabelHeaders) {
            pivotTable.addColumnLabel(var.getFunction(), var.getColumnIndex(), var.getHeaderName());
        }

        if (sortColumnIndex != null) {
            pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(sortColumnIndex)
                    .setSortType(STFieldSortType.ASCENDING);
        }
        // addColumnLabel(pivotTable, sheet, dataArea, 1);
        return pivotTable;
    }
```

Comment: To be able to answer why something is **not** working, one needs a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For Apache POI using an existent Excel file that means: 1. Complete compilable code, not only code snippet of one method. (Complete code means code able to copy, paste, compile, run) 2. The file used. 3. Hint which Apache POI version used.